# How to add X-API-Key and X-Session to header using Retrofit library?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, httpurlconnection

I want to use `Retrofit` library instead of `HttpURLConnection` for my `multipart request` to send image to server. My `HttpURLConnection` request is not working for some reason.

But I have problem in `Retrofit` and I don't know how to add `Session token` and `API key` to my request.

This is solution I'm using for every request with `HttpURLConnection`(and its working for everything but multipart request):

```
val con = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
con.apply {
    requestMethod = method
    useCaches = false
    doOutput = true
    doInput = true
    addRequestProperty(HEADER_CONNECTION, "Keep-Alive")
    addRequestProperty(HEADER_CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache")
    addRequestProperty(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data")
    addRequestProperty("X-API-Key", apiType.apiKey)
    addRequestProperty("X-Session", getServerSession())
}
```

And this is my request using Retrofit library:

```
val f = File(app.cacheDir, filename)
f.createNewFile()

val fos = FileOutputStream(f)
fos.write(data)
fos.flush()
fos.close()

val reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), f)
val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", f.name, reqFile)

val httpUrl = HttpUrl.Builder()
    .scheme("https")
    .host(mainUrl)
    .addPathSegment(apiSegment)
    .addQueryParameter("X-API-Key", apiType.apiKey)
    .addQueryParameter("X-Session", getServerSession())

val service = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(httpUrl.build()).build().create(Service::class.java)
val req = service.postImage(body)
val response = req.execute()
```

I've used `addQueryParameter`, because I read that this is the way how to add those 2 parameters to header, but this will only affect my URL for API call and it will add API Key and Session to URL, which is not recognized by server at all.

UPDATE:

My Interface for Post Service:

```
internal interface MultipartService {
        @Multipart
        @POST("{url}")
        fun postImage(@Part image: MultipartBody.Part): Call<ResponseBody>
        fun setEndpoint(@Path("url") endpoint: String): Call<ResponseBody>
    }
```

UPDATE: FIXED

```
   internal interface MultipartServicePost {
        @POST("{url}")
        @Multipart
        fun postImage(@Part image: MultipartBody.Part, @Path(value = "url", encoded = true) endpoint: String): Call<ResponseBody>
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addQueryParameter()` is, like the name says, for adding parameters in the Query.

What you want is an `Interceptor`. Here is an example :

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        Request request = original.newBuilder()
            .header("X-API-Key", apiType.apiKey)
            .header("X-Session", getServerSession())
            .method(original.method(), original.body())
            .build();

        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

Regarding the dynamic urls, you can define dynamic path segments when you define your interface. Example :

```
public interface PostService {  

    @GET("/posts/{post_id}")
    Task getPost(@Path("post_id") long id);
}
```

Comment: This is working. I have one question about URL passing. Is there any way how to change post URL for my API Call? Because If I use HttpUrl and `.addPathSegment()` it will add weird `%2F` string between segments.

URL consists of "https:/" + baseURL + /apiVersion/ + /apiFunction/ + /name/ 
And those 3 are dynamic and could be changed. So I cant add them to @Post inside Service interface.

Comment: Ok, cool (don't forget to upvote and validate the answer...). Regarding you comment, do you mean you want dynamic urls ? It's possible when you define your interface

Comment: Yes. Almost everything is dynamic. I can change entire API url (Im using multiple API servers with this multipart request) So the best way would be that I can append bunch of url parts into one String and I want to use it as URL. Similar to HttpUrlConnection. I can create URL object consists of multiple url parts glued together.

Example: `val url = URL(apiType.url + apiBasePath + apiPath + apiName + apiSubName)`

Comment: I've tried it as it should be done in Kotlin (without Task) but it caused error: `HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.)` And there is `@POST("{url}")` in interface (see edited question)

Comment: @GET(), @POST(), etc. are parts of retrofit2. But you can't do what you've posted : the `@POST("{url}")` must be written just above your `setEndpoint()` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196699/discussion-between-martin1337-and-bruno).